# Crash after updating Facebook Audience Network 6.5

Tags: java, android, view, facebook-audience-network

I had recently updated SDK of Facebook Audience Network to 6.5 and am suddenly facing crash, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: (Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class com.facebook.ads.internal.util.parcelable.WrappedParcelable instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x3.

I am not able to see this id in my code there is no mapping file, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Do you have a solution for this problem? Please share –